# Regex matching groups number

Tags: regex

I am learning regex and ran into a problem.
I have the following:

`href="http://google.com/topic/713725-dogs-are-great-3"> href="http://google.com/topic/213225-humans-are-great"> href="http://google.com/topic/342315-cats-are-great-but-small">`

with this code
`href="(?:[^"]*)topic/([^<]*)">`

i can select

`713725-dogs-are-great-3 213225-humans-are-great 342315-cats-are-great-but-small`

but i only want to match the numbers

342315
213225
713725

any ideas?

Comment: you could find `/topic/(\d{6})-` .. but using an intermediate XML parser will help you out! see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4541045

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following regex; which will create 1 capturing group which you can use to grab the matched value.

```
\bhref="(?:[^"]*)topic\/(\d+)-.*">$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/ZCjut9/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
\bhref="          ##Matching href using \b before it as a word boundary followed by =" here.
(?:[^"]*)topic\/  ##In a non-capturing group matching till " everything till topic/
(\d+)             ##Creating 1st capturing group which has digits in it.
-.*">$            ##Matching everything till " followed by "> till end of value.
```